# rspec double('output').as_null_object still results in failures

Tags: rspec

We upgraded to Rspec 2.14.5 and ruby 2.0.0p195.

It appears the example in The Respec Book (page 53) that uses `double('output').as_null_object` as an approach to the failure due to multiple puts from the `game.start` method continues to fail.

I think I have checked and rechecked the text I have typed in.  I have double checked to make the sure the prompt text is correct (the code with just the first text was working properly - now it fails because it sees the second puts).  Has there been a change in the `.as_null_object` specification?  Has this problem been seen by anyone else?